# Compare 2 Homography matrix in Opencv with C++ code

Tags: c++, opencv, homography

My idea is using homography matrix for misalignment detection.
First I put 2 image (Calib1 image and Calib2 image) that aligned and calculation homography matrix call h1 or calibration homograph.
After that my code will be processed next 2 image (Reference image and image need to be scan) and calculate second homography matrix call h2.

if is there some thing miss alignment beetween 2 image (Reference image and image need to be scan) the homography matrix h2 > h1  as the result [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAhcz.png)

the code like: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xAyS.png)

But i can't compare the homography as access the elements of  cv::Mat

Comment: you can review my code on github link: https://github.com/HaPuLo/image_processing/blob/homography/Source.cpp

Comment: Anybody can help me